# What is the meaning of Bob's words?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Paul found some Nazi Vinyl records in Bob's house, so he asked about him it.

> Bob: Not mine. Nazi stuff belongs to Moburg.
>
> Paul: Moburg lives here?
>
> Bob: He keeps his uniform here. I never see him from **one month's end to
>   the next.**

I didn't understand "**one month's end to the next**" in his words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand from this is, Bob sees Moburg only on month ends.

His exact words are **"I never see him from one month's end to the next."**

I think Bob is saying , He has to wait till next month's end to see Moburg again.

You can also take it as, Bob sees Moburg very rarely, ie of course once a month.